# Vagrant: vagrant up command gives "A box must be specified" error

Tags: laravel, terminal, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am getting this error when trying to run the "vagrant up" terminal command:

> *There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:*
>
> **A box must be specified.*

In my `Homestead/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox` folder, there is no file there, so I'm assuming that is what it's referring to when it says a box must be specified, however I don't know how to include a box as this is my first time using vagrant, and I've searched online with no resolve.

Anyone have a solution to this?

EDIT (Vagrantfile):

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
    elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
        Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
    end

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this by fixing my file paths in the homestead.yaml. When I made the installs in the terminal, a .homestead folder was being create outside of the main Homestead folder, which is what was causing my problems. But after changing the paths inside that .homestead/homestead.yaml to the same ones in my Homestead/homestead.yaml, the problem no longer persisted.

Answer (score 6):

Inside the homestead directory, you have to run the command `bash init.sh`.

This will generate the `Homestead.yaml` file (and `after.sh` and `aliases`) inside your home directory (`~`).

If you are changing `Homestead.yaml` again, you have to re-run `bash init.sh` again. It will ask for overwrite, say yes.

(also, be sure that the directory for `folders: - map:` exists)

Comment: But doesn't the bash init.sh command overwrite homestead.yaml? That's what happens on my machine. If I edit the homestead.yaml file and use bash init.sh, my changes are reverted. I'm new to homestead, trying to set it up, so far no luck.

Answer (score -2):

Use `homestead up` instead of `vagrant up`, if you are using homestead package. It already knows where all files are and will up you VM easily.

Comment: homestead up gives an error saying no such file or directory